# What is the music theoretical basis for this chord transition?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I've got a song on the piano, which I've been learning for years now and for which I just recently decided to actually dive into a chord analysis.
Early on in the piece, there's this climactic build of chords that transitions into the next portion of the song and goes: D-D-?-Dm7-Dm7-Gm-(start of next portion with a D)
The problem is that I just can't figure out the question mark chord. It contains C#, E, F, and A, making it kinda like a Dsus2 over A except without the D...

That seems odd, so I could use some help identifying what the chord is, and what sense it makes from a music theory perspective!

Image of the phrase for added context: [image: Image of the phrase]

Comment: Music theory is talking about musical practices. The title makes it sound like there was such a thing as _THE_ music theoretical basis for the chords, as if there was one Correct Way of talking about it or looking at it. :) And of course, it would follow that other ways must be incorrect or wrong. I disagree with this implication. There are many ways of thinking about it and talking about it.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXqNyWehVEQ

Comment: piggybacking off of @piiperiReinstateMonica - music theory is based off of music, not the other way around. While you can certainly use theory as a creative jumping off point, the only actual rule that music has to follow is that people like it or find it interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chord is a combination of an A/C# and a Dm chord. I wouldn't give it a name. The composer wants the whole passage to sound like it continues to hammer out Dm chords, but they also want the chromatic movement of the descending bass. Hence both the F-A of the Dm and the C#-E of the A. You can call this a "poly-chord", or consider both the C# and the E as passing tones between the Dm and the Dm/C chords.

Answer (score 2):

It's `Dm A/C# Dm7/C` with the `F5` held during the change through `A/C#`.

With `C#` and `E` in the outer voices and an `A` included it has all the tones and movement of `Dm: i V6`, and I think that progression sounds out pretty clearly.

You could call the `F5` a non-chord tone, perhaps a *pedal* or a sort of *suspension*.

To make the point about `Dm: i V6` cleared just play the `F5` as `G5` and the progression will become a clear `Dm: i V6/5`. To play `F5` or `G5` in an inner voice doesn't really obscure the main harmony that much.

Another way to look at it is a progression simply of `Dm Dm7/C` where the non-chord tones are the `C#` and `E` which would be called *passing tones*.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you elaborate a little on what the notation `Dm: i V6` means? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: That's Roman numeral analysis, Roman numerals assigned to each of the scale degrees which are the roots of chords. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis

Comment: I see, so the "Dm: ..." just indicates that you're talking about the Dm scale here? (This was my confusion ^^)

Comment: @MitchellFaas, not the scale, the _key_. Scale and key are not synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

It's an A maj aug 5.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_sixth

That part is just bouncing between a Dm and A maj. The F is just carrying over to the the Dm7.

Comment: By looking only at the notes one could call it an A+. Except that it has both E and F, and F is not an aug 5, it's a minor 6. But that ignores the harmonic function. The whole function of that C# is to go to C natural, as a chromatic bass line. Calling it an A chord of any stripe -- and therefore having somesort of dominant function -- misses that.